# Sem resposta de conexão PHP

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, script, integração

Boa noite, alguém poderia me ajudar? Estou fazendo um projeto academico onde tenho que linkar páginas em HTML e fazer elas puxarem informações do banco de dados.

Até o momento, criei uma tabela no meu banco de dados, criei um script php para conectar e coloquei o form na página html como um botão. Quando clico no botão ele me trás o código do php em uma página web. Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: isso que aparece na imagem]

obs: o arquivo está como php e estou abrindo a página web e na página web estou apertando no botão.

Comment: Olá Aleeh, Bem-vindo ao fórum. Sugiro que leia o tour (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funcionam as coisas aqui na comunidade. Para que o pessoal consiga te ajudar aqui vão 2 dicas: Coloque o código através do atalho `ctrl + k` e não uma imagem. Outra dica é explicitar qual o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Na conexão com o BD, você está passando uma "variável" `$123`, mas nomes de variáveis em PHP não podem começar com números e, nesse caso, nem está sendo declarada. Acho que você queria escrever `$senha`.  O mesmo acontece com `$servidor` e `$usuario`.

```
$link = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
```

Além disso, não sei que versão do PHP você está usando, mas `mysql_connect` foi *deprecated* na versão 5.5.0 e removida na versão 7.0.0. Da [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php):

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0

#### FUNÇÃO `mysqli_connect`

Você pode usar `mysqli_connect` (note o **i** junto à palavra **mysql** - *i* é de *improved*/melhorado).

```
$link = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
```

Opcionalmente, você pode usar [`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) para se conectar ao BD. Nesse caso, não adicione o parâmetro `$banco` em `mysqli_connect`.

#### MAIS FUNÇÕES

Você pode buscar por mais funções na documentação do PHP [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php). 
Há, inclusive, a opção de usar a classe `mysqli` (orientação a objetos).

Comment: Eu já alterei o código pra mysqli, mas a execução permanece a mesma. Será que meu form está correto?                                                                         
                <div id="content-wrap">
             <div id="content" class="clearfix">
               <h3 class="yellow f14">Consulte os candidatos:</h3>
               <form name="Cadastro" action="consulta.php" method="POST">
 <input type="submit" name="consulta-completa" value="Consulte aqui">
</form>           
            </div>

Comment: O script que você postou apenas abre a conexão com o BD. Se não estiver aparecendo erros na página (e o debugger estiver ativo) não há erros. Mas verifique a senha, e usuário de conexão com BD. Posta o restante do seu código para tentarmos ajudar. Você pode editar a sua pergunta e postar nela.

Comment: No script que você postou não está sendo feita a pesquisa no DB. Você precisa usar `mysqli_query` para a executar sua query de `SELECT`.